# Boot drive is taking too much space

Tags: windows-8.1, memory

My Laptop is running on Window 8.1 pro single language. and my boot drive is 224 GB. Two days ago when i check my drive size it is showing `1.63 GB free from 224 GB`. I dont know why. when i check the size of all folders in that drive (including hiddan files and folders) it was showing only 58.7 GB.

#### What have i tried

1. I tried disk cleanup. doesn't work
2. Deleting Restore Point, doesnt work

Comment: Try checking your disk again with [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/)?

Comment: [Tips to free up drive space on your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/free-up-disk-space)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for commenting but i tried almost all methods given in the link.

Comment: "i tried almost all methods" > what about the ones you didn't try yet?

Comment: Try turning off Hibernation (powercfg -h off) from command line with administrator access. This will usually get you a fair chunk of space back. But, do run WinDirStat or SpaceMonger (v1.4 is free) - make sure you run as admin - and find out exactly where the files are stored or eating up your space. 224GB for windows only (and no other software) is not normal. If you have installed various other software... well thats kinda expected.

Comment: im trieng those @DavidPostill

Comment: @Darius only visual studio and SSMS installed. that takes ~ 15 - 20 GB

Comment: Seyren , @Darius thanks WinDirStat work like a charm, an extra ldf file is created in sqlsercer folder. I deleted it and it free my 165 GB memory. Can you answer it, i will accept as an answer.